# Do event listeners persist while the DOM object is hidden

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm trying to optimize my code and I couldn't find anything on whether or not I should temporally remove the event listeners while the DOM elements display is set to none

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you! I only have 4 "on mouse downs", but I'm developing an io game and so I'm trying to make sure weaker CPU's aren't getting throttled. Do you think this will be fine and what's a good tool to run a performance test?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you! that pretty much covers my question, should I delete the question or ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do persist, but it's almost certainly not something to worry about - if you want to optimize for performance, run a performance test so you can analyze things properly, and make fixes as needed. (best not to prematurely optimize).

If you only have 4 listeners, the CPU impact will definitely be next to nothing - inside the listeners, simply check whether the current `display` is `none` at the beginning, and if it is `none`, don't run any more code in the listener - just `return` early.